# Caml query how to get data witin date range

Tags: caml-query

For example, I reservation on 6/10/2016 - 8/10/2016. When I search start date on 7/10/2016 and end date is 7/10/2016 it do not show anything. if I use

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
     <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2016-10-07T18:37:21Z</Value>
     </Gt>
     <Lt>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2016-10-07T18:37:24Z</Value>
     </Lt>
  </And>
 </Where>
</Query>
```

It show every rows that pass 7/10/2016 too. I want to only show  6//10/2016 - 8/10/2016.How to fix this.

Comment: If you are agreed to any answer then you can accept / mark as useful :)
Hope below answer is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention the **Less than and Equal** and **Greater than Equal**.

Instead of  **use**  and  **use** 
Then you can get the proper result as you expected.

Please [click here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42592/date-ranges-in-caml-queries#answer-42593) for reference.

**Also this question is [repeated](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42592/date-ranges-in-caml-queries)**.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<Geq>` & `<Leq>` instead of `<Gt>` & `<Lt>` opearator in caml query

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
     <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2016-10-07T18:37:21Z</Value>
     </Geq>
     <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>2016-10-07T18:37:24Z</Value>
     </Leq>
  </And>
 </Where>
</Query>
```